# change font of a string in C#

Tags: c#, fonts

I am reading a txt file and writing it's content to another txt file.
Before writing the content to new file i have to change the font of the string (string that is read from another file).
How should i do this.
Please help.

Comment: Wait, what?? What kind of file are you reading/writing to/from?

Comment: What format is the file you are writing? That's fundamental to how you would change the font.

Comment: what is the file? discussing fonts doesn't make any sense without discussing what the file is...

Comment: You don't change the font of a string, you change the font that a control uses to display the string.

Comment: What you mean by `font of the string` is not clear. Are you referring to the encoding of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings don't inherently *have* fonts. If the string represents RTF or something like that, then that's a different matter - it's effectively changing the font within the RTF format.

However, if you're just writing a plain text file, it's entirely up to the display client which font it uses.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry!! friend. you can't change the fonts or size of string. C# don't know where your are going to write the string text... Console or any text file or label...

Just think what happens if it supports, lets u set some format to string and in place of writing to a file you are printing to console (Console is not rich in fonts)

anyway !! but if you want to do it, it depends on the type of file you are writting. notepad, or rtf orword document. There you can find changing fonts very easily.

Answer (score 1):

If it is pure text file, then you cannot!
If you are writing a Word Doc, using some Office API then you can!

Answer (score 1):

a simple string has no font. A font is used for printing or displaying a string, but a string itself is only text. If you are talking about some encoded text (like rtf) you are reading, you will need to parse the text into something interpretable and go on from there.

If you only want to put out one or more strings in a textbox using different fonts, you will need to use a control that supports formatting.

Comment: Your first paragraph is reasonable if you assume the OP is using the correct terms, the second is a leap that's not even implied anywhere. No down vote from me but I would avoid assumptions (unless explicitly stated as such) as they can lead to confusion, i.e. someone searching for textbox and font might find themselves in this question ;)