# Can't convert string to font in C#

Tags: c#

```
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
Font font = (Font)converter.ConvertFromString("[Font: Name=Arial, Size=48, Units=3, GdiCharSet=0, GdiVerticalFont=False]");
this.Font = font;
```

> Error => System.ArgumentException: 'Value of 'Size=48, Units=3, GdiCharSet=0, GdiVerticalFont=False]' is not valid for 'units'.'

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039543/change-font-of-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Judging by the example in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontconverter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) the string doesn't look like it has the right format, can you elaborate on how you came about using that format?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontconverter(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples Your string looks wrong

Comment: Please be aware that `Font.ToString()` does not return a string suitable for `FontConverter`. Use `FontConverter` to also convert the font to a string to get something it can convert back. In particular, you likely want this string: `"Arial; 48pt"`

Comment: Be aware that this might be culture dependent. So make sure you convert it back and forth within the same culture. (The semicolon in the example of Lasse is the character that could change between cultures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you've used the `Font.ToString()` method to produce a string which `FontConverter` doesn't support.

Instead you should use `FontConverter` to also produce the string and you would get back a string that looks like this:

```
Arial; 12pt; style=Bold
```

The same font object run through its `.ToString()` method gives:

```
[Font: Name=Arial, Size=12, Units=3, GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]
```

For your particular string you should use this string instead:

```
"Arial; 48pt"
```

Comment: Be aware that this might be culture dependent. So make sure you convert it back and forth within the same culture. (The semicolon in the example string is the character that could change between cultures).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
Font font = (Font)converter.ConvertFromString("Arial, 48pt");
this.Font = font;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't well documented by Microsoft.

However, if you look at the [reference source for `FontConverter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/FontConverter.cs,c4714f31a3a6e49c) you'll see the following:

```
internal class UnitName {

    internal string name; 

    internal GraphicsUnit unit;

    internal static readonly UnitName[] names = new UnitName[] {
            new UnitName("world", GraphicsUnit.World), // made up
            new UnitName("display", GraphicsUnit.Display), // made up
            new UnitName("px", GraphicsUnit.Pixel),
            new UnitName("pt", GraphicsUnit.Point),
            new UnitName("in", GraphicsUnit.Inch),
            new UnitName("doc", GraphicsUnit.Document), // made up
            new UnitName("mm", GraphicsUnit.Millimeter),
        };


    internal UnitName(string name, GraphicsUnit unit) {
        this.name = name;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

So it looks like you should be specifying the units as one of:

```
world | display | px | pt | in | doc | mm
```

You will need to postfix one of those values to the size value. The comment in the source code says:

```
text is expected to have a format like " 8,25pt
```